# Определение пустой ячейки

Tags: wpf

Как определить пустая ли определенная ячейка в Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так?

```
static bool AnyInCell(Grid grid, int x , int y )
{
  foreach (UIElement elem in grid.Children)
  {
    int fromX = Grid.GetColumn(elem);
    int toX = fromX + Grid.GetColumnSpan(elem) - 1;
    int fromY = Grid.GetRow(elem);
    int toY = fromY + Grid.GetRowSpan(elem) - 1;
    if (fromX <= x && x <= toX && fromY <= y && y <= toY)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```